# Ignore error while opening Excel workbook

Tags: vba, excel

I've an Excel VBA Code, that Code will Merge All Excel Files located in one folder.
I need that Code to ignore any files that does not open for one reason or another like, the file is corrupted or not compatible or ....

the code is :

```
Sub simpleXlsMerger()
Dim bookList As Workbook
Dim mergeObj As Object, dirObj As Object, filesObj As Object, everyObj As Object
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Set mergeObj = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

'change folder path of excel files here
Set dirObj = mergeObj.Getfolder("C:\Users\user\Desktop\Stock- Pharmacies - Copy\Airport STK 15-12-2015\New folder")
Set filesObj = dirObj.Files
For Each everyObj In filesObj
Set bookList = Workbooks.Open(everyObj)

'change "A2" with cell reference of start point for every files here
'for example "B3:IV" to merge all files start from columns B and rows 3
'If you're files using more than IV column, change it to the latest column
'Also change "A" column on "A65536" to the same column as start point
Range("A1:IV" & Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Row).Copy
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Activate

'Do not change the following column. It's not the same column as above
Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial
Application.CutCopyMode = False
bookList.Close
Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Try adding to the begining `Application.DisplayAlerts = False` and the `Application.DisplayAlerts = True` at the end

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't really have a way to check if the file is good.  You might be able to handle it with some error handling.  See the two `On Error Goto` statements and the `NextIteration:` label.  Give that a try.

```
Sub simpleXlsMerger()

    Dim bookList As Workbook
    Dim mergeObj As Object, dirObj As Object, filesObj As Object, everyObj As Object
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Set mergeObj = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

    'change folder path of excel files here
    Set dirObj = mergeObj.Getfolder("C:\Users\user\Desktop\Stock- Pharmacies - Copy\Airport STK 15-12-2015\New folder")
    Set filesObj = dirObj.Files
    For Each everyObj In filesObj

        On Error Goto NextIteration
        Set bookList = Workbooks.Open(everyObj)
        On Error Goto 0

        'change "A2" with cell reference of start point for every files here
        'for example "B3:IV" to merge all files start from columns B and rows 3
        'If you're files using more than IV column, change it to the latest column
        'Also change "A" column on "A65536" to the same column as start point
        Range("A1:IV" & Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Row).Copy
        ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Activate

        'Do not change the following column. It's not the same column as above
        Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
        bookList.Close

NextIteration: 'This is your goto label

    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Actually this method is not working, I'm thinking of something similar to "if statement", if the file could be opened and read from excel go ahead, other wise go next file in that directly.

Comment: @Hatem Husam I changed the answer to a different approach.